# Class property as class name

Tags: php, class, properties, static

```
$this->property = 'SomeClass';

$x = new $this->property();     // works
$x = $this->property::create(); // fails (parse error)
```

Is this a bug in PHP?

Can a static method be called using the property, without assigning the value to a new variable, and using that variable instead?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: php 5.3.0. does it work in others?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  This behavior is in the comments for the scope resolution operator doc, but the operator isn't in the precedence chart in the operator documentation for some reason.  From what I can tell you can't chain :: with anything, including itself.  The ability to use a variable to refer to the classname with :: was new in 5.3, but I guess they didn't go any further than that.

Comment: @Alex, why don't you use `$x->create()` because you have an instance of `SomeClass`, anyways, you can't do that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been entered as a bug for a few months and is still in Open status, so I'm gonna go with yes.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61397

Similarly,

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54095

Answer (score 2):

Use `call_user_func`

```
$x = call_user_func(array($this->property, 'create'));
```